# Python absolute value

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
x = 25
epsilon = 0.01
numGuesses = 0
low = 0.0
high = max(1.0, x)
ans = (high + low)/2.0
while abs(ans**2 - x) >= epsilon:
    print ('low =', low, 'high =', high, 'ans =', ans)
    numGuesses += 1
if ans**2 < x:
    low = ans
else:
    high = ans
ans = (high + low)/2.0
print ('numGuesses =', numGuesses)
print (ans, 'is close to square root of', x)
```

Hi All.

I have a question regarding the line `while abs(ans**2 - x) >= epsilon:` from the above code. I thought that `abs` would  matter only in case of the negative numbers but leaving only `while (ans**2 - x) >= epsilon:` causes a problem finding a square root. Why? What am I missing here?

Comment: The indentation of your code is wrong: the `if` block should probably be indented. About your question: why do you think that `ans**2 - x` always should be positive? By running the code, you should see that `ans` is sometimes lower than sqrt(x).

Comment: Rolled back edit as it inadvertently fixed the issue. Please be careful of changing indentation in other people's Python questions.

Answer (score 0):

It was a indentation error in code:

```
x = 25
epsilon = 0.01
numGuesses = 0
low = 0.0
high = max(1.0, x)
ans = (high + low)/2.0
while abs(ans**2 - x) >= epsilon:
    print('low =', low, 'high =', high, 'ans =', ans)
    numGuesses += 1
    if ans**2 < x:
        low = ans
    else:
        high = ans

    ans = (high + low)/2.0
    print ('numGuesses =', numGuesses)
    print (ans, 'is close to square root of', x)
```

## output:

```
('low =', 0.0, 'high =', 25, 'ans =', 12.5)
('numGuesses =', 1)
(6.25, 'is close to square root of', 25)
('low =', 0.0, 'high =', 12.5, 'ans =', 6.25)
('numGuesses =', 2)
(3.125, 'is close to square root of', 25)
('low =', 0.0, 'high =', 6.25, 'ans =', 3.125)
('numGuesses =', 3)
(4.6875, 'is close to square root of', 25)
('low =', 3.125, 'high =', 6.25, 'ans =', 4.6875)
('numGuesses =', 4)
(5.46875, 'is close to square root of', 25)
('low =', 4.6875, 'high =', 6.25, 'ans =', 5.46875)
('numGuesses =', 5)
(5.078125, 'is close to square root of', 25)
('low =', 4.6875, 'high =', 5.46875, 'ans =', 5.078125)
('numGuesses =', 6)
(4.8828125, 'is close to square root of', 25)
('low =', 4.6875, 'high =', 5.078125, 'ans =', 4.8828125)
('numGuesses =', 7)
(4.98046875, 'is close to square root of', 25)
('low =', 4.8828125, 'high =', 5.078125, 'ans =', 4.98046875)
('numGuesses =', 8)
(5.029296875, 'is close to square root of', 25)
('low =', 4.98046875, 'high =', 5.078125, 'ans =', 5.029296875)
('numGuesses =', 9)
(5.0048828125, 'is close to square root of', 25)
('low =', 4.98046875, 'high =', 5.029296875, 'ans =', 5.0048828125)
('numGuesses =', 10)
(4.99267578125, 'is close to square root of', 25)
('low =', 4.98046875, 'high =', 5.0048828125, 'ans =', 4.99267578125)
('numGuesses =', 11)
(4.998779296875, 'is close to square root of', 25)
('low =', 4.99267578125, 'high =', 5.0048828125, 'ans =', 4.998779296875)
('numGuesses =', 12)
(5.0018310546875, 'is close to square root of', 25)
('low =', 4.998779296875, 'high =', 5.0048828125, 'ans =', 5.0018310546875)
('numGuesses =', 13)
(5.00030517578125, 'is close to square root of', 25)
```

Comment: Yeah in the if statement only . Not at the end of the code where "Prints" are. Thanks

Comment: @dexter7d anytime ;)

Answer (score 0):

The point you are missing is that the value of `x` might sometimes be greater than `ans**2`, so that the expression `ans**2 - x` might become negative.

Here are the first lines of the script's output:

```
('low =', 0.0, 'high =', 25, 'ans =', 12.5)
('low =', 0.0, 'high =', 12.5, 'ans =', 6.25)
('low =', 0.0, 'high =', 6.25, 'ans =', 3.125)
('low =', 3.125, 'high =', 6.25, 'ans =', 4.6875)
('low =', 4.6875, 'high =', 6.25, 'ans =', 5.46875)
('low =', 4.6875, 'high =', 5.46875, 'ans =', 5.078125)
...
```

By looking at the output you will see that `ans` will be 3.125 in the third iteration, while `x` is still 25. Thus the expression `ans**2 - x` will be negative. Therefore we need `abs()` in the loop condition.